# Black screen when assigning google maps to subview

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to load places inside Google Map View for iOS6.
How to set the frame for the Map ?
Currently it is fullscreen

```
 -(void)loadView {

   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                        longitude:76.316142
                                                             zoom:15];
   mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
   self.view = mapView_;

   }
```

I tried by creating a new (small) view inside the current view and add map inside that,but at that time the page is not getting loaded.It shows a full black screen

```
 -(void)loadView {

  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                        longitude:76.316142
                                                             zoom:15];
   mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

   [self.view Addsubview:newView];
   self.newView = mapView_;

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution.
Remove the loadview method, and put the following code in the view did load method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) camera:camera];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.

    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];

[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: I tried the solution you proposed but it still gives a black screen. I have a outlet to my `viewcontroller.h` file for the UIView I added named as `myView`. I used `self.view` as well as `self.myView` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: looks fine.. what's the CGRect returned by view.bounds?

Answer (score 1):

if you put into loadView it wont have a view.. the xib isn't even loaded...
put it in **viewDidLoad**

and do

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the declaration @property for GMSMapView , if it is weak property then make it strong.

@property (strong,nonatomic)GMSMapView *mapView;

Comment: Your answer made my day. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

By removing func loadView from my code fixed my problem

```
    override func loadView() {

}
```

Or by putting this line of code inside the loadView

```
    override func loadView() {
            self.view = GMSMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
```